# Menu com DropDown por trás do conteúdo da página

Tags: css, menu, dropdown

Boa tarde!

Peguei um menu com dropdown (tipo "hover") pronto na internet. Mas o submenu está aparecendo por trás do conteúdo da página e exibe uma barra de rolagem na vertical.

Alguém já passou pelo mesmo problema?

Segue meu código html:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
   overflow-x: hidden;  
}

html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.logo-araguaina { 
   float: left;
   height: 80px;
}

.titulo-cabecalho {
   float: left;
   margin-left: 18%;
   margin-top: 2%;
}

.nome-usuario {
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    top: 40px;
}

.link-logout {
    position: relative;
    left: 30%;
    top: 25px;
}

.alerta-erro {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    margin-left: 41.5%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.alerta-sucesso {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 39.5%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: green;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.cabecalho {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}



/* Reset CSS */
*, *:after, *:before{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
/* Fundo do menu */
.menu{
  background: #000;
}
/* Remove as bolinhas do lado das listas */
.menu .menu-list, .menu .sub-menu{
  list-style: none;
}
/* Configura todos os links do nosso menu */
.menu a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing:0.2em;
}
/* Faz os <li>s ficarem na horizontal */
.menu > .menu-list > li{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
/* Configura os links do menu principal */
.menu > .menu-list > li > a {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background: #000;
}
/* Configura o fundo do menu principal quando com mouse hover */
.menu > .menu-list > li:hover a {
  background: #444;
}
/* Mostra o submenu no evento de mouse hover */
.menu > .menu-list > li:hover > .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
/* Configura o estilo do submenu */
.menu > .menu-list > li > .sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 5px;
  background: blue;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
}
/* Configura os links do submenu */
.menu > .menu-list > li > .sub-menu > li > a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}
/* Clearfix para o menu */
.menu:after {
  content: '.';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está APENAS em:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Esse código está restringindo a altura da página apenas ao conteúdo dela (*note uma pequena barra de rolagem vertical à esquerda da barra do menu*), ou seja, como o submenu é um elemento `absolute`, vai ficar por trás da área que não faz parte do conteúdo da página.

**Solução:** remova o código acima que é totalmente desnecessário e o submenu irá aparecer normalmente.

***Dica:*** remova o `overflow-x: hidden;` do `body` porque é desnecessário também.

Comment: É isso msm Dvdsamm, acabei descobrindo eliminando item por item no css até achar onde estava o erro, mas vou marcar sua resposta como a solução, pq foi exatamente o que eu fiz. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Rodei na minha máquina local (com o xamp) e deu tudo certo, veja só:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbvRH.png

Verifique se o seu navegador está atualizado, se continuar tente adicionar ao css dos elementos que estão aparecendo por trás a propriedade z-index e seta um valor numérico para tal, por exemplo:

```
.menu{
   z-index: 10;
}
```

Se ainda continuar aparecendo por trás de outro elemento, aumente o valor setado.

Comment: Igor, fiz a alteração sugerida, mas ainda continua com o mesmo problema. Lembrando que o submenu já está configurado com z-index: 1000.

Segue imagem do problema: https://imgur.com/a/8NAJB

Comment: Fiz o mesmo menu em um arquivo de teste no bloco de notas e funcionou normalmente, somente nesse projeto que estou usando o C# asp.net que não funciona. Provavelmente tem alguma configuração no meu CSS que está causando o problema.

Comment: Qual servidor que você utiliza? rodei na minha maquina com o XAMPP e o LARAGON  e deu tudo certo, verifique se o que você utiliza está atualizado ou tente rodar com o  XAMPP

Comment: Resolvi Igor. 

O problema estava no CSS, eu declarei o overflow-x no body e no html como hidden, quando retirei esse estilo, funcionou normalmente. Não sei qual a relação do overflow-x com o dropdown, mas funcionou.

Agradeço a ajuda.